# Why does traveling through Hyperspace look different depending on the point of view?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, hyperspace

Looking from inside a ship, through a window, white or blue lines in black space are seen when a ship is traveling through Hyperspace.

[image: Hyperspace from the Falcon's cockpit]
[image: Hyperspace from Ackbar's ship]

However, from the outside, a blue, cloudy tunnel is seen.

[image: Hyperspace outside of the Falcon]
[image: Hyperspace - Clone Wars]

Is there an explained reason for this?

Comment: Because that's what looked best to the producers. It's not as if there's anyone outside the ship to see that perspective.

Comment: how is this a plot inconsistency?

Comment: @phantom I incorrectly thought it was one.

Comment: @RogueJedi, you're going to find that many of the special effects we cling to depend greatly on our own point of view.

Comment: @DougWarren - You win the interwebs.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The stretching stars is **only** seen just as a ship *enters* and *exits* hyperspace, showing the ship's acceleration/deceleration. However, **once lightspeed is achieved**, all that can be seen is the cloudy blue hyperspace tunnel (whether inside the ship or not).

**Entering** hyperspace (as seen in the third [Star Wars: The Force Awakens trailer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sGbxmsDFVnE&t=1m17s)):

[image]

**Exiting** hyperspace (as seen in *[Return of the Jedi](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xPZigWFyK2o&t=0m58s)*):

[image]

Comment: This can also be seen in *Return of the Jedi*--watch the scene where Lando first travels to Endor in the Millennium Falcon (about an hour and half into the movie), you see the "hyperspace tunnel" effect from *inside* the cockpit (with the backs of Lando and his copilot seen onscreen at the same time), and then as they drop out of hyperspace, the tunnel turns into streaking stars, which resolve into normal stars once they have fully exited hyperspace. If anyone could make a gif of this scene, or at least get some screenshots, it'd be helpful.

Comment: The scene I'm talking about with Lando can be seen starting 58 seconds into [this youtube clip](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xPZigWFyK2o). Also if anyone's interested, [this site](http://www.theforce.net/swtc/hyperspace.html) has a lot of good info on how hyperspace seems to work in Star Wars, based on a combination of the movies and EU information, and maybe some fan speculation too.

Comment: Wow. First time I'm seeing that video and it looks so awesome. The hyperspace transition was one of those things that blew me away back in 1977 and I still love it today.

Comment: thanks @Hypnosifl for the clip, I finally got around to creating a gif out of it. First time for everything. :)

Comment: Do we know if this "blue tunnel" effect was there in the original _Return of the Jedi_, or whether it was added in one of the many SFX retcons/remixes? I have the suspicion it wasn't there in early versions (my childhood memories are distinctly of the stretching stars, but none of the blue tunnel).

Comment: @AndresF. I too think that was added in the 1997 re-releases.