# What is hyperspace in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars, technology, hyperspace

Is it teleportation, making a wormhole, or something else? Does it always exist and people just go into it, or does someone create it for themselves when they jump? Does it manipulate time?

Comment: You might want to indicate what sources you are looking to find answers in.  I have posted the answer implied by the original trilogy of films, but there are likely to be other explanations in extended universe works.

Comment: How does Star Wars matter, here? Though the Question might have been inspired by Star Wars, you seem to be Asking simply what hyperspace is. What did I miss?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin different franchises often have different forms of hyperspace. Hyperspace in SW is influenced by matter in realspace, which is why it requires hyperspace lanes for safe travel. Hyperspace in the Stargate franchise, for example, doesn't appear to have the same limitation.

Comment: @jaxad0127 Jolly good and how was that not covered in my query? Of course Stargate and Star Wars have different ideas and that's about their technology and logistics, not at all their concepts of hyperspace. In fact, it's questionable whether Stargate recognises the concept of hyperspace.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin For a more extreme example, look at Warhammer 40k; that's a very different type of hyperspace than SW or SG. Since we're talking fiction here, what hyperspace means can very greatly. So referencing SW in the question is appropriate, as the questioner wants information relevant to that franchise.

Comment: @jaxad0127 If you think the Question was meant to be "How is is hyperspace different in Star Wars?" that's up to you. If the Question is as written, "What is hyperspace in Star Wars?" then don['t you see how lazy it looks?

Comment: Question doesn't seem lazy to me.  "In Star Wars" implies either, "as opposed to in general", or, "I have literally no concept about other SF hyperspace at all so I believe this to be something specific to SW".  OTOH "How is hyperspace different in SW?" implies, "I think hyperspace is generally the same everywhere in SF but SW it seems different; how?" which doesn't seem to be the intention.

Comment: This might be completely incorrect, but "hyperspace" may have been derived from "[hyperbolic space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_space)," which is a form of [hyperbolic geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_geometry). This means that it has a negative (sectional) curvature, and looking at artistic impressions of wormholes, it also seems like those have negative curvatures. (A negative curvature means that the circumference of a small circle with radius r will be greater than 2πr, or that triangles are [hyperbolic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_triangle).)

Comment: @Robbie Goodwin - since when specificity became laziness?

Answer (score 26):

It is a '*dimension of space-time*', '*coterminous with realspace*'.

> For those who are unfamiliar with hyperspace, **it is
> a dimension of space-time that can be entered only at
> faster-than-light speeds**. While the most knowledgeable
> astrophysicists and astrogation experts admit that
> some aspects of hyperspace remain a mystery, **it is
> understood that hyperspace is coterminous with
> realspace**: each point in realspace is associated with
> a unique point in hyperspace, and adjacent points in
> realspace are adjacent in hyperspace. In other words,
> if you travel 'north' in realspace as you jump into
> hyperspace, you will head 'north’ into hyperspace too.
> Also, every object in realspace has a ‘shadow’
> in hyperspace. For example, there is a star (or star-
> like body) in hyperspace at the same location as it
> occupies in realspace. Such 'shadows’ are potentially
> lethal obstacles for travelers in hyperspace, which
> is why pilots rely on astrogation computers to plot
> courses around the mass shadows, allowing travel from
> one point in realspace to another.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Millennium Falcon Owners' Workshop Manual](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/YT-1300_Millennium_Falcon_Owners%27_Workshop_Manual)</sup></sub>

It is usually referred to as an 'alternate dimension'.

> Hyperdrives allow starships to travel faster than the speed of light, crossing space through **the alternate dimension of hyperspace**. Large objects in normal space cast “mass shadows” in hyperspace, so hyperspace jumps must be precisely calculated to avoid collisions.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars Databank: Hyperdrive](https://web.archive.org/web/20191123102636/https://www.starwars.com/databank/hyperdrive)</sup></sub>

Comment: This implies hyperspace is exactly like real space except "smaller", which in my opinion is indistinguishable from "going faster".

Comment: Note that, in math, "hyperspace" has a specific meaning, e.g., [What is hyperspace in linear algebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1089017/602049) states that "In linear algebra text(Hoffman), it says "In a vector space of dimension n, a subspace of dimension n−1 is called hyperspace"." This is roughly consistent with what you wrote. Also, in theory at least, traveling in an appropriate space with one less dimension could allow you to get to a destination much faster than you would be able to otherwise moving at the same "speed".

Comment: "can be entered only at faster-than-light speeds" -- muh, and since one can't travel faster than light in realspace, no one can't get to hyperspace?

Comment: @JohnOmielan I don't think that meaning of "hyperspace" is standard, outside of the textbook mentioned in that question. For a subspace of dimension n-1 inside a space of dimension n, I've almost always seen and heard the term "hyperplane", not "hyperspace". In occasions, the word "hyperspace" is used to mean "a space whose dimension could be more than 3", to make a clear distinction with the world's physical 3d-space, and I think most mathematicians I know would assume that meaning; although in practice, everyone just says "space" and never "hyperspace".

Comment: @user19087 Probably more like (going faster) ²

Comment: @Stef Thank you for those details. It's been almost 40 years since I last took classes in, and generally used, linear algebra. Thus, my memory is fuzzy, but I don't recall "hyperspace" ever being defined or used back then. As such, "hyperspace" is likely at least not a common term (as well as being non-standard as you state) in math. Nonetheless, many years ago I heard or read about "hyperspace" also being a math term, which is why I searched online to find that reference and wrote my comment.

Comment: @ilkkachu: I know, right?  In most sci-fi settings, hyperspace exists to allow effectively-FTL travel without violating relativity.  In Star Wars, the world-building details exist to explain / justify movie dialogue that sounded cool but presumably wasn't thought through in physics terms, like the fact that characters say "make the jump to light-speed".  Or "made the Kessel run in under 12 parsecs". Thus going to or past light-speed must be how you *enter* hyperspace, if you take that dialog to it's literal meaning without going one step further to worry about actual physics.

Comment: so hyperspace is something like the feywild in DND, or the dark world in Zelda?

Comment: @clockw0rk - More like the shadow realm in Legacy of Kain, but sure. Your things are fine too

Comment: @user19087 I don't think it implies that hyperspace travel is indistinguishable from going faster. It implies the spatial rules are essentially the same, but not that the physical laws are -- e.g. perhaps inertia behaves differently. There's also an asymmetry in that there's no indication that hyperspace objects have real-space shadows, so perhaps a ship traveling through hyperspace crashing into a real-space ship would be catastrophic for the hyperspace ship but go completely unnoticed by the real-space ship.

Comment: The thing that's always driven me crazy in SW is that there is _zero_ explanation of how _long_ it takes to travel in hyperspace. In ROTJ, we don't know how long the Rebels' journey to Endor takes, while in _Rogue One_, they make it from Yavin to Scarif during the course of a single battle, implying that a journey across the galaxy (if http://www.swgalaxymap.com/search/ is anything to go by) takes just a few hours. That's the only world-building about hyperspace that's really needed, in my opinion: how long a journey takes. The physics of it can just be hand-wavy Force magic. :P

Comment: @Rabadash8820 - You should ask a question about how long it took for the rebel fleet to get from Sullust to Endor.

Comment: @Valorum Looks like there was some [healthy discussion](http://www.starfleetjedi.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=821) on this back in 2008. Long story short, nobody knows, and certainly nobody knows how real-space velocities transform to hyperspace velocities :P

Comment: @Rabadash8820 - I took the liberty of asking (and answering) [your question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/259224/how-long-did-it-take-for-the-rebel-fleet-to-reach-endor-from-sullust) - Approx 30 mins.

Answer (score 12):

It’s not entirely clear, and the explanation varies based on the source you look at.

There are only a few things that are generally consistent about hyperspace across all major canon:

- It allows FTL travel in some way.
- For most races, it requires special technology to utilize it, which is lacking on some starships. Two notable examples of ships lacking a hyperdrive in the primary canon being most TIE fighters (with the notable exception to the exception being Vader’s TIE Advanced) and the Delta-7 Aethersprite and Eta-2 Actis light interceptors used by the Jedi in Episodes II and III (the big ring things with engines they dock with are external hyperdrive units).
- Some space-based life has evolved to utilize it. The sole example in current canon are the purrgil, seen in some episodes of *Star Wars: Rebels*.
- It is affected in some way by gravity wells. In most sources where this is explicitly mentioned, it’s implied that you can’t jump at all if you’re deep enough in a gravity well and that passing through a gravity well while in hyperspace pulls you out of hyperspace (the Imperial Interdictor-class Star Destroyers, seen in numerous recent sources, work on this principle). In some other cases it’s implied that you *can* jump inside a gravity well, it’s just really dangerous and it may not be possible to get beyond the gravity well.

Beyond that, it’s all speculation. The special effects in the original releases of Episodes IV and V for hyperspace travel look suspiciously similar to the VFX for warp speed in *Star Trek*. The special effects in at least some releases of Episode VI and most of the media since then look suspiciously similar to the time tunnels seen on occasion in *Doctor Who*. None of the movies ever get into an explanation of how it works, and I’m pretty sure none of the TV series do either.

The exact explanation in current canon appears to be that it’s an alternate dimension of time and space. Exactly *what* that means is unclear though (it could be referring to the compressed space produced by something like a warp drive, or it could be some parallel reality, or it could even just be an on-demand wormhole).

The primary explanation in the comprehensive legends canon appears to be somewhat similar and a bit more fleshed out, with the description being relatively consistent with what ‘hyperspace’ usually means in most modern sci-fi (that is, an alternate dimension with a 1:1 mapping of points to realspace, where physics are altered from realspace just enough in some way to allow much faster transits between two points than would normally be possible between the associated points in realspace).

Some older third-party extended universe sources have descriptions which are inconsistent with this, but they are mostly ignored in other media.

---

All of this is nice, but the reality is that *Star Wars* is science-fantasy, not science-fiction, and hyperspace, alongside most other ‘technology’ was really just supposed to be magic. FTL travel is a necessity for the type of story being told, so it has to exist in some form, but because the way it works is not actually relevant to the plot (well, in any of the original media it’s not, some extended-universe stuff actually does include stories where how it works is relevant) it never gets explained. This is one of numerous examples of Lucas doing a good job of adhering to the core principle of good drama: ‘Only include details that matter to the plot or are required to set the mood.’.

Comment: Upvoted for the "science-fantasy" part after the last divider. As that great philosopher Triumph the Insult Comic dog once said about a similar Star Wars question, "The correct answer is: Who gives a sh*t?"

Answer (score 10):

From the original trilogy, it is evident that "hyperspace" is just a name, and the travel does not appear to take place outside of normal space.  There are are at least two definite indications of this.

First, note that as ships accelerate to hyperspace speeds, they see the stars stretch out, indicating that they have reached faster-than-light speeds while still seeing starlight in normal space.

Second, Han Solo's description of hyperspace navigation in *A New Hope* indicates that normal-space objects are still obstructions to craft traveling through hyperspace.

> **Han:**  Traveling through hyperspace ain't like dusting crops, boy! Without precise calculations we could fly right through a star or bounce too close to a supernova, and that'd end  your trip real quick, wouldn't it?

Comment: Later works have probably retconned this, but for me, original trilogy canon always wins.

Comment: But even in *Return of the Jedi*, we see that the stretching stars thing only happens when transitioning into or out of hyperspace, the actual hyperspace trip looks like traveling through a cloudy blue tunnel -- see the second gif in [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/106902/22250).

Comment: "indicates that normal-space objects are still obstructions" - either that, or that the listed objects (in particular, stars or supernovae) inherently "reach into" hyperspace in some fashion.

Comment: @Hypnosifl I have the suspicion -- but cannot be sure -- that blue tunnel in Return of the Jedi is one of Lucas' many SFX retcons/remixes. I don't remember seeing the blue tunnel at all in my childhood Star Wars marathons. Sadly, I don't have access to any of the earlier versions...

Comment: @AndresF. - archive.org has a [scan of an original 16mm print](https://archive.org/details/ROTJ16mm), If you go to 1:33:20 you can see the blue cloudy tunnel was there in the original (you can verify that this isn't a print of a special edition if you go to 12:20 where the musical number in Jabba's palace features a non-CGI Sy Snootles). It's very brief so it's not surprising one wouldn't remember it from childhood viewings.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - In the EU/Legends (and now in the Disney canon) it was explained that large masses in real space like stars cast a [mass shadow](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Mass_shadow) in hyperspace. Based on the "sources" section of the Legends part of the wookieepedia article, it looks like this term was first published the [1987 roleplaying game](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Roleplaying_Game_%28first_edition%29), though [this article](https://starwars.fandom.com/f/p/2991806052296557889) mentions some parts of the RPG drew on "archival material" from Lucasfilm.

Comment: Another interesting thing to note is that the speed of ships in hyperspace varies wildly with the path they need to take; it's never made clear if that's due to some inherent properties of hyperspace being different in different regions, or just something like needing to calculate many paths (or just making multiple individual jumps) in more densely packed neighbourhoods or something. And neither canon nor EU mention those lanes changing over time (other than in response to something like supernovae explosions) despite the fact that all those stars move with respect to each other a lot.

Comment: @Luaan, frankly, that was the most frustrating thing about the Death Stars and Starkiller base. As a fan who was fully sold on the gravity of realspace objects controlling the shape of nearby hyperspace lanes, I always wanted to know what effect dispersing a planet's mass across the solar system would have on intergalactic trade as the existing pathways were disturbed. Maybe my headcannon wasn't ever really correct, but I vaguely remember it being mostly explained in Tales of the Jedi: The Golden Age of the Sith 1.

Comment: That dialog sounds more like it has to worry about *some* of the spacetime in-between, but not necessarily **all** of it. It wouldn't be inconsistent with a folded space model, or with one where a ship periodically "bounces" out of hyperspace into realspace, perhaps using large gravity wells to help slingshot itself. It could even be consistent with just being worried about missing the destination and ending up in one of those hazards instead. (eg: We're off by a bit, and instead of coming out in orbit of Alderan, we come out flying straight into its sun).

Comment: @T.E.D. A common trope of FTL in older sci-fi was that the whole thing was incredibly computationally intensive - so the real limit to speed in FTL was how fast your computer was able to calculate a safe path. Better computers (and maps) allowed you to make longer jumps and/or more frequent ones. Presumably, this would involve things like simulating the movement of stars and planets with respect to the light lag along the path. Star Wars does have ships _travelling_ FTL, rather than appearing at the other end right away, but with such ridiculous speeds, navigation has much the same problem.

Comment: @Luaan - Celestial bodies and groups of bodies are all moving, rotating, and orbiting around other things independently of each other, so it isn't tough to imagine that any calculation that has to take a large amount of them into account would get very wild very quickly.

Comment: ...still, I'd think that just getting the math for ONE body at the destination correct enough that you could aim yourself at that point from 100's of light-years away and be confident to not accidentally end up in its star instead would be beyond what our present-day computers can manage. At the absolute least you'd need floating point numbers outside the resolution of IEEE 64-bit, and instruments that can measure your real-world orientation to the target with that level of resolution (which is also why I think "bouncing" out into normal space to make adjustments periodically seems feasible).

Comment: @T.E.D. Yeah, or at least slowing down (Star Wars civilizations have FTL sensors, but being able to see 100 ly ahead isn't enough when you can cross that distance in a fraction of a second - the hyperdrive turns off automatically, but that's usually _way_ too late). Lanes that are known to be relatively devoid of obstacles over long time periods would be rather valuable - for example, it's how the droid army got to Coruscant in the opening of RotS; they acquired a route that went straight there from uncontested space, allowing the rare surprise attack.

Comment: @T.E.D. It's weird they don't seem to use out-of-plane travel much, given those constraints, though. Perhaps the benefit of having a clear travel for most of your trip is not enough to outweigh the lack of navigation data out and back - indeed, it seems that there's a backbone of tradelanes that crisscrosses the SW galaxy much the same way rivers would in real-life, and systems in the right spot can get obscenely rich without doing much.